# Paw - Support for https mutual (client-side cert) authentication?

Tags: authentication, ssl, https, certificate, paw-app

Trying out PAW and liking it very much.
The only thing I don't manage to get working is using HTTPS mutual auth. Some of the APIs I need to interact with require mutually authenticated https.

How do I tell PAW to use a cert to authenticate? The cert is already in OSX Keychain and Safari can do GETs to that API without problems, so I (hope) it should be doable...

Not being able to do this might be the make/or break for PAW for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for late answer. We want to add client-side certificates on Paw for a long time, and it's probably for the next major release...

Comment: @MichaMazaheri thanks for the info -- any estimated dates for that release?

Comment: yeah, we're thinking about a month or so...

Comment: Great news! I've bitten the bullet and bought the software in advance -- hope you don't plan to raise prices too much :)

Comment: No we aren't, "we're the good guys" ;)

Comment: . Looking forward to the update notification then ;)

Comment: I need this feature too. I'm putting 11 november in my calendar. What's the progress?

Comment: @MichaMazaheri any news on update?

Comment: https://twitter.com/luckymarmot/status/668507673273479168 :)

Answer (score 0):

While you are waiting for the next version of Paw, you can use SoapUI to test a REST interface with SSL client authentication: http://geekswithblogs.net/gvdmaaden/archive/2011/02/24/how-to-configure-soapui-with-client-certificate-authentication.aspx